# Filtering python logging module to only log last line of an exception?

Tags: python, exception, error-handling, try-catch, python-logging

I'm utilizing the following code to print exceptions from a python module I'm running inside of my script:

```
        except Exception as e:
          logging.info('yt-dlp initated a break', exc_info=True)
```

Currently it outputs much more information than I need.

Something along the lines of:

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/web_ripper.py", line 58, in subscriptions_loop
    ydl.download([url])
  File "/app/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/yt_dlp/YoutubeDL.py", line 3113, in download
    self.__download_wrapper(self.extract_info)(
  File "/app/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/yt_dlp/YoutubeDL.py", line 3086, in wrapper
    res = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/yt_dlp/YoutubeDL.py", line 1344, in extract_info
    return self.__extract_info(url, self.get_info_extractor(ie_key), download, extra_info, process)
  File "/app/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/yt_dlp/YoutubeDL.py", line 1371, in wrapper
    self.report_error(str(e), e.format_traceback())
  File "/app/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/yt_dlp/YoutubeDL.py", line 912, in report_error
    self.trouble(f'{self._format_err("ERROR:", self.Styles.ERROR)} {message}', *args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/yt_dlp/YoutubeDL.py", line 853, in trouble
    raise DownloadError(message, exc_info)
yt_dlp.utils.DownloadError: ERROR: [youtube:tab] Videogamedunkey: Unable to download API page: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

What's the most efficient way to simply print the last line of the exception?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Formatting exceptions as Python does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35498555/formatting-exceptions-as-python-does)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom [`Formatter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Formatter) that will process the `exc_text` of the `record` you are trying to log.

The following `MyFormatter` will check if the record has an exception text. If not, it will create it using `self.formatException`. Then, since `record.exc_text` is a string storing the trace as text, with `\n` as separators between lines, you can keep the last line using `.split("\n")[-1]`.

```py
import logging

class MyFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def format(self, record):
        # https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L711
        if not record.exc_text:
            record.exc_text = self.formatException(record.exc_info)
        record.exc_text = record.exc_text.split("\n")[-1]
        return super().format(record)
```

Then, add the following code to use your new `MyFormatter`:

```py
def a(x):
    return b(x)

def b(x):
    return c(x)

def c(x):
    return d(x)

def d(x):
    return x / 0

logger = logging.getLogger("foobar")
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
stream_handler.setFormatter(MyFormatter(fmt="%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"))
logger.addHandler(stream_handler)

try:
    a(1)
except Exception as e:
    logger.info('yt-dlp initated a break', exc_info=True)
```

and you get:

```
foobar - INFO - yt-dlp initated a break
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

instead of the previous:

```
foobar - INFO - yt-dlp initated a break
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "70704112.py", line 31, in <module>
    a(1)
  File "70704112.py", line 12, in a
    return b(x)
  File "70704112.py", line 15, in b
    return c(x)
  File "70704112.py", line 18, in c
    return d(x)
  File "70704112.py", line 21, in d
    return x / 0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```